# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$cancelled

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, codeigniter

I got this error message when running PHP Code Igniter project:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$cancelled

Filename: transactions/transtable.php

Line Number: 38

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-inventory-and-sales-management-system\application\views\transactions\transtable.php
Line: 38
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-inventory-and-sales-management-system\application\controllers\Search.php
Line: 103
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-inventory-and-sales-management-system\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

**Here is the code where the error occurs.**

```
<?php foreach($allTransactions as $get): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?= $sn ?>.</th>
                    <td><a class="pointer vtr" title="Click to view receipt"><?= $get->ref ?></a></td>
                    <td><?= $get->quantity ?></td>
                    <td>&#8373;<?= number_format($get->totalMoneySpent, 2) ?></td>
                    <td>&#8373;<?= number_format($get->amountTendered, 2) ?></td>
                    <td>&#8373;<?= number_format($get->changeDue, 2) ?></td>
                    <td><?=  str_replace("_", " ", $get->modeOfPayment)?></td>
                    <td><?=$get->staffName?></td>
                    <td><?=$get->cust_name?> - <?=$get->cust_phone?> - <?=$get->cust_email?></td>
                    <td><?= date('jS M, Y h:ia', strtotime($get->transDate)) ?></td>
                    <td><?=$get->cancelled? 'Cancelled' : 'Completed'?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $sn++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-inventory-and-sales-management-system\application\views\transactions\transtable.php Line: 38 Function: _error_handler**

**File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-inventory-and-sales-management-system\application\controllers\Search.php
Line: 103
Function: view**

```
public function transSearch()
  {
    $data['allTransactions'] = $this->transaction->transsearch($this->value);
    $data['sn'] = 1;

    $json['transTable'] = $data['allTransactions'] ? $this->load->view('transactions/transtable', $data, TRUE) : "No match found";

    //set final output
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($json));
  }
```

**File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-inventory-and-sales-management-system\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once**

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: Could you show the `transsearch` method from your model?

Comment: @Marleen, you mean transsearch.php ?

Comment: I mean the class that has this function in it: `$this->transaction->transsearch($this->value);` I assume that is your model class.

Comment: @Marleen, here it is

  public function transSearch()
  {
    $data['allTransactions'] = $this->transaction->transsearch($this->value);
    $data['sn'] = 1;

    $json['transTable'] = $data['allTransactions'] ? $this->load->view('transactions/transtable', $data, TRUE) : "No match found";

    //set final output
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($json));
  }

Answer (score 0):

Using `isset()` function to check is property have value

```
<td><?= isset($get->cancelled) ? 'Cancelled' : 'Completed' ?></td>
```

Or using `property_exists()` function to check if object have the key.

```
<td><?= property_exists($get, 'cancelled') ? 'Cancelled' : 'Completed' ?></td>
```